# Obtain value from another class

Tags: java

I want to obtain a value from class A to class B via a setter and getter.

In class A, I've set the setter and getter like so:

```
public class A {
    String value;

    public String getvalue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setvalue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    ...

    public void taskA() {
         GsonRequest<> myReq = new GsonRequest<>(someTask());
    }

    private someTask(){
         String encrypted = "Some string";
         setvalue(encrypted);
    }
}
```

In class B, I wanna use the getter in class A to obtain its value.

```
public class B {

    A a;

    private void callTask() {
         a = new A();

         Log.d("Value", a.getvalue());
    }
}
```

"value" returns null. How do I fix this?

EDIT: I'm doing this on my Android project.

Comment: Where is `e_password` declared? And where do you assign it?

Comment: Sorry, it was meant to be `value`. Forgot to change it (for the sake of simplicity)

Comment: All answers should be deleted now :D

Comment: You don't seem to set `value`. I mean in `Class B` you create an object of `A` but that doesnt seem to initialise the value you want. For intialisation you need to set the value with `setvalue` before you call `getvalue`

Comment: a = new A(); - you created a class, but haven't assigned anything to `value`. It is initialized, but not defined.

Comment: u need to call method someTask first

Comment: Have you used the debugger to check whether the value is set at some time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `value` is not initialized before use and it being `String` type, the default value is `null`. Hence you are getting value as `null`.

You need to explicitly set `value` using its setter method as below.

```
private void callTask() {
    a = new A();

    //Set Value Here
    a.setvalue("Your Value Goes Here ");  

    // Get Value Here
    Log.d("Value", a.getvalue());
}
```

Comment: The only correct answer :) +1

Comment: Wait, I don't get it. So I have to set the Value "manually" from Class B, and not class A? How do I get the value from class A then? o.o

Comment: @AimanB - *I want to obtain a value from class A to class B via a setter and getter* - Without using the setter to set the value, its pointless to use the getter to get the value. And you're getting the value from class `A` only.

Comment: @AimanB :Setter and Getter methods are meant to be accessed from classes other than itself.

Comment: So, I can't really obtain the `value` from class A via its getter?

Comment: @AimanB - You can get the `value` from class `A` via its getter. Just that without initializing it you'll only get `null`. Either set a value using the getter or do it via a constructor.

Comment: yes you can using classAObject.getValue(), but this will always return value as null until you explicitly set value="XXX"; in class A or from class B add this code fragment classAObj.setValue("XXX");

Answer (score 0):

You have to return the `value`

```
 public String getvalue() {
    return value;
 }
```

And make sure you are setting the value for `value` before get that. Else that will return it's default value which is `null` here

Comment: Sorry, it was meant to be `value`. Forgot to change it (for the sake of simplicity)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you just want to pass the reference of a created object from class "A" to a method or constructor of class "B":

```
public class B {

    private void callTask(final A a) {

         Log.d("Value", a.getvalue());
    }
}
```

Of course you need to create the object of class "A" before you pass it to "callTask(A)" method of class "B".